# How to make a loop which exits after true value

Tags: c++, loops

What loop should I use to make user input value again if statement is false?
I mean there are max 31 days in a month so if user inputs 32, program will ask to type again, and if statement is true then loop exits.

```
int main()
{
    int day;
    cout<<"Enter a day"<<endl;
    cin>>day;
        if(day<32){
    // class Input
    Input inObject(day);
    // printInput(){cout<<"Today is the "<<input<<endl;}
    inObject.printInput();
    }else{
        cout<<"Incorrect day! Enter again."<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (bool valid_input = false; !valid_input;) { /**/ }` ?

Comment: you can use any loop and exit it on whatever value you want to exit  on.

Comment: Learn about `break` statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (int day; std::cout << "Enter a day: " && std::cin >> day; )
    {
        if (day > 31)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid day, try again.\n";
            continue;
        }

        Input inObject(day);
        // ...
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    std::cout << "Premature end of input!\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

You can refine this by reading string lines rather than ints. The present code will fail entirely once you enter a non-integer. A possible improvement:

```
for (std::string line;
     std::cout << "Enter a day: " && std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int day;
    if (!(iss >> day >> std::ws) || iss.get() != EOF || day > 31)
    {
        /*error*/
        continue;
    }

    // as before
}
```

Comment: Why did you hide the most important statement behind right border of the scrollable code box?

Comment: @JanHudec: Your screen must be this wide to have fun :-S Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

A generalized approach to your problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template<typename Ty>
struct CheckedIn
{
    CheckedIn(std::function<bool(Ty)> fn): m_fn(fn) {}
    CheckedIn(std::string prompt, std::function<bool(Ty)> fn):m_prompt(prompt), m_fn(fn) {}
    CheckedIn(std::string prompt, std::function<bool(Ty)> fn, std::string errormsg):
        m_prompt(prompt), m_errormsg(errormsg), m_fn(fn) {}
    CheckedIn& operator>>(Ty _in)
    {
        do
        {
            std::cout << m_prompt;
            std::cin >> _in;
        } while(m_fn(_in) && std::cout<<(m_errormsg==""?"Invalid Input":m_errormsg));
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::function<bool(Ty)> m_fn;
    std::string m_prompt;
    std::string m_errormsg;
};

int main()
{
    int day = int();
    CheckedIn<int>("Enter a day: ", 
                   []( int day){return bool(day > 31); },
                   "Invalid day, try again.\n") >> day;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is dangerously broken, as it [ignores the result of the I/O operation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/596781).

Comment: And have you actually tested this?